# Geometric multiplicity equal to 0

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Is it possible for an eigenvalue of endomorphism to have geometric multiplicity equal to 0?

I would be grateful if anyone who has an answer to this question would care to explain.

Answer (score 10):

No -- if $\lambda$ is an algebraic eigenvalue at all, then *by definition* $A-\lambda I$ has determinant zero, which means that the equation $(A-\lambda I)x=0$ has at least one nontrivial solution for $x$. This solution is an *eigenvector*, so the eigenspace must have dimension at least $1$.

Comment: What would this vector be for a non-trivial rotation matrix in 2D, zero vector?

Comment: @Yola a rotation matrix (as far as I know) has (a) complex eigenvalue(s), meaning the eigenvector(s) is/are also complex (a+ib, while a and b are both vectors with real parameters).